# Is it possible to specify a custom likelihood function using the "link" variable in the `glm` package?

Tags: r

I am trying to create a custom likelihood function that uses different likelihood functions depending on whether an observation is endogenous or exogenous. Is it possible to hardcode my function using the link variable in the `glm` function in the `glm` package? Or would I have to do everything by hand and then use an optimization procedure like `optim`? Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

It seems to be possible, since MASS appears to add the negative binomial (with specified $\theta$).

If it was me trying to do it, I'd probably start with "`quasi`" and the ability in `glm` to define both link and variance functions as described under those arguments in the help on `glm`

Comment: Thank you for the response. Forgive my question, but I looked up the `quasi` function but am not sure what it does exactly. Would yu know what role it plays? Thank you!

Comment: Quasi just operates off the mean and variance specifications; it's effectively like ML for whatever distribution corresponds to the variance function (... possibly times a scaling factor - for example quasi Poisson is effectively like fitting a Poisson with an unknown scaling factor). I'd think if you aren't familiar enough  with GLMs to know how quasi models work, you probably don't have enough background to do what you're trying to do. I'd go with some good basic books on GLMs first.